# Deleting nodes in ll

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to create a function that deletes pairs of values within a singly linked list

i.e if a list was 1->2->2->3->4->nullptr it would be 1->3->4->nullptr and 1->2->3->3->3->4->nullptr would be 1->2->3->4->nullptr

This is what I have so far:

```
void remove_pairs_i (LN<T>*& l) {
for(LN<T> * x = l; x->next != nullptr; x=x->next)
{
 if(l == nullptr)
 {
    return;
 }
    if(x->value == x->next->value) {

        LN<T> *d1 = x;
        LN<T> *d2 = x->next;
        x = x->next->next; //point x to the node after the pair to be deleted

        delete d1;
        delete d2;
    }
}
```

}

However, when I test the function against 1->1->2->3->nullptr
my program just ends with return 0 so it is hard to tell what is happening, even if I hand simulate it.

Comment: You assign `x` to `x->next->next`, but `x` is a local variable. Additionally you have to assign the `next` of the element before `x` to `x->next->next`, to take the two elements out of the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the next value of the node previous to equal pair.

In the special case when the equal pair are in the begining of the list, then the head of the list should be modified.

```
void remove_pairs_i (LN<T>*& l)
{
    // If two first values are equal, the head of the list should be modified
    while (l && l->next && l->value == l->next->value)
    {
        LN<T> *d1 = l;
        LN<T> *d2 = l->next;
        l = l->next->next; //point l to the node after the pair to be deleted

        delete d1;
        delete d2;
    }

    // Rest of the list
    for(LN<T> * x = l; x && x->next && x->next->next; x = x->next)
    {
        if(x->next->value == x->next->next->value)
        {
            LN<T> *d1 = x->next;
            LN<T> *d2 = x->next->next;
            x->next = x->next->next->next; //point x->next to the node after the pair to be deleted

            delete d1;
            delete d2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. May I ask a simple question? in the for loop, for the condition, what exactly is that saying? is it saying "as long as x, and x->next. and x->next->next are true(not null)? proceed?

Comment: Exactly. It is _convenient_ to check that x exists before accessing any of its members.

Comment: do you mind removing your answer? it is sorta built off my code and it appears someone has the exact same question as I do (theyre probably in my class) and I don't want them to have the same solution as me as we could get in trouble

Comment: You should have probably thought of that before getting someone on SO to do your homework for you...